# SelectNodes .length returns 0

Tags: xml, xpath, vbscript

so I'm in big trouble atm: I parse a XML-File, and for that I'll want to count all entrys. My code works well, but I tested it with a very big XML-File and nothing happend. So I tried to figure out, where the error is.

```
Dim nodeCount : nodeCount = oXML.SelectNodes("/root/abc/*").length
```

This works for XML-Files up to 6.000 Entrys(Around 40k-Lines of Code), but If the number is bigger, it returns 0. So I have no idea, how to fix this.

Comment: I think, that SelectNode can't hold that many entrys..

Comment: Are you sure it is related to the size? The usual problem with XPath not selecting the nodes you think it should select is namespaces, i.e. a default namespace declaration like `<root xmlns="http://example.com/ns">...</root>` which puts the `root` and its descendants into the namespace (e.g. `http://example.com/ns`) and that way the path `/root/abc` which selects elements in no namespace does not find any elements.

Comment: your `oXML` Variable is Full. when you input the original xml into that variable it runs out of space.

Comment: have you found a work around for this issue?  I would love to see it, I work with VBscript to work with a Vendor's application.

Comment: No sorry, I disassemble the big XML-File so I don't have that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in VBScript the largest Variable that you get for text is a string and it will only hold about 2 billion characters.

[VBScript Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

after the variable (`oXML`) runs out of space it just cuts off and with out the closing tags the xpath won't query correctly and will not return any data.

Have you tried to write the code in Regular VB, you would have bigger variable types? is that even an option?